# Why does iOS auto layout lead to apparent rounding errors on pre-Retina displays (unit test included)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, retina-display

I'm currently having a hard time understanding why the following unit test fails on an iPad 2.  Auto layout seems to slightly (by 0.5 points) mis-position `view` inside `superview` relative to the exact centering that's required by two layout constraints. What seems especially strange is that the crucial test (but-last assertion) passes on an iPhone 5, so the apparent rounding error affects only one (iOS 6) platform. What's going on here?

**UPDATE 1** I've changed the code to ensure that that both frames are sufficiently constrained in terms of widths and heights even if `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is `NO`, as suggested as a possibly related remedy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16928777/1789384). However, this apparently does not change the situation.

```
#import "BugTests.h"

@implementation BugTests

- (void)testCenteredLayout {
    UIView *superview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 88)];
    superview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    superview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;

    UILabel *view = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    view.text = @"Single Round against iPad.";
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0.0 constant:206.0]];
    [view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0.0 constant: 21.0]];

    [superview addSubview:view];

    [superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

    STAssertEquals(superview.center, CGPointMake(384, 44), nil); // succeeds
    STAssertEquals(view.center,      CGPointMake(  0,  0), nil); // succeeds

    [superview setNeedsLayout];
    [superview layoutIfNeeded];

    STAssertTrue(!superview.hasAmbiguousLayout, nil);

    STAssertEquals(superview.frame.size, CGSizeMake(768, 88), nil); // succeeds
    STAssertEquals(view.frame.size,      CGSizeMake(206, 21), nil); // succeeds

    STAssertEquals(superview.center, CGPointMake(384, 44), nil); // succeeds

    STAssertEquals(superview.center, view.center,            nil); // fails: why?
    STAssertEquals(view.center,      CGPointMake(384, 44.5), nil); // succeeds: why?
}

@end
```

**UPDATE 2** I've isolated another instance of (apparently) the same problem in a second unit test. This time it involves a top (not center) constraint, and this time a fractional point coordinate seems to be the trigger. (The test succeeds also on pre-Retina devices e.g. with `y = 951`, i.e. an odd point coordinate.) I've checked in various simulator configurations (next to my physical iPad 2 and iPhone 5) occurence indeed seems tied to the absence of a Ratina display. (Again, thanks to @ArkadiuszHolko for the lead.)

My current sense from these tests is that one has to avoid odd heights and fractional y-coordinates if point-exact auto layout on pre-Retina displays is required. But why?

```
- (void)testNonRetinaAutoLayoutProblem2 {
    UIView *superview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004)];
    superview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    superview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;

    CGFloat y = 950.5; // see e.g. pageControlTopConstraint

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading        multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing       multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop            multiplier:1.0 constant:y]];
    [superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0.0 constant:8]];

    [superview addSubview:view];

    [superview setNeedsLayout];
    [superview layoutIfNeeded];

    STAssertTrue(!superview.hasAmbiguousLayout, nil);
    STAssertTrue(!view.hasAmbiguousLayout,      nil);

    STAssertEquals(superview.frame, CGRectMake(0, 0,       768, 1004), nil); // succeeds
    STAssertEquals(view.frame,      CGRectMake(0, y,       768,    8), nil); // fails: why?
    STAssertEquals(view.frame,      CGRectMake(0, y + 0.5, 768,    8), nil); // succeeds: why?
}
```

Comment: Does it happen only on iPad 2 on iOS 6?

Comment: @ArkadiuszHolko The issue shows up on iPad 2 running iOS 6.1.3. It does not show up on iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1.4. These are the latest iOS 6 releases. I currently have not got the means to test on iOS 7. What else could I try?

Comment: Can you see what happens when you change the height of the `view` from 21 to 22? Are the results now consistent between iPhone and iPad? iPad doesn't have the retina display, that might have caused the difference.

Comment: If I change the height of `view`from 21 to 22 the issue doesn't show up any more. (Thanks for the suggestion!) The problem is that unlike in the simple unit test where I isolated the problem, in the real app some of these coordinates are calculated not simply set. I hasten to modify all these calculations before I have a better understanding of the nature and validity of the root cause. Perhaps it's something about the combination of odd point coordinates, auto layout, and a pre-retina iPad display, as you comment seems to suggest.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you've shown is that autolayout abhors misaligned views. On non-retina devices the closest *pixel* is the nearest **point**, so it rounds to whole numbers. On retina screens the closest *pixel* is the nearest **half point**, so it rounds to the nearest .5. You can demonstrate this by changing y in your second test to 950.25 and noting that view.frame remains {{0, 950.5}, {768, 8}} (instead of changing to {{0, 950.25}, {768, 8}}).

(Just to prove that it is rounding and not `ceil`ing, if you change y to 950.2 view.frame becomes {{0, 950}, {768, 8}}.)

Comment: So an implicit constraint whereby views must align exactly to whole pixel coordinates has higher priority than all explicit constraints, I suppose ...