# Add a 0.5 point height subview to UINavigationBar not show in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiview, uinavigationbar

I have a class inherit from `UINavigationBar` and I want to add a separator line as its subview to separate the navigation bar and the navigation content.

The line's height is defined as following.

```
#define SEPERATOR_LINE_HEIGHT (1.0f / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale)
```

My code:

```
@interface MyPopNavigationBar : UINavigationBar
@end

@implementation MyPopNavigationBar {
    UIView *separatorLine;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;
        self.translucent = NO;

        separatorLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) - SEPERATOR_LINE_HEIGHT, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), SEPERATOR_LINE_HEIGHT)];
        separatorLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        separatorLine.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
        [self addSubview:separatorLine];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This works well in both iOS 6 and iOS 8 (all Retina), but I can't see my `separatorLine` in iOS 7 (Retina, too)!

iOS 6 & 8:

[image: iOS6_8]

iOS 7:

[image: iOS7]

Besides, when I tried to set the separator line height to exact 1, it shows in all iOS versions.

```
separatorLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) - 1, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), 1)];
```

[image: allversion]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by myself. It's the `autoresizingMask`'s fault . I strongly suspect this a bug of iOS7.

I print the `recursiveDescription` in lldb, only to find the height of `separatorLine` is autoresized to zero in iOS7! In contrast, the value is 0.5 in iOS8.

So, remove this line:

```
separatorLine.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

And set the frame in `layoutSubviews` method of `MyPopNavigationBar` again to make it correct:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    separatorLine.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) - SEPERATOR_LINE_HEIGHT, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), SEPERATOR_LINE_HEIGHT);
}
```

Then the line displays in all iOS versions.

Comment: [There is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349072/why-does-ios-auto-layout-lead-to-apparent-rounding-errors-on-pre-retina-displays) is a similar question.