# How to reduce 1px gap between two UI elements in a tight grid layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout, grid-layout

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641910/creating-a-3x3-grid-with-auto-layout-constraints) great answer for 3x3 ggrid layout of `UIImageViews`.

I used a freeform IB whihc has size 600x600. I placed UIViews in the IB in 3x3 layout.

Each `UIImageView`s is of size 200,200 and placed at

```
      (0,0)   (200,0)   (400,0)
      (0,200) (200,200) (400,200)
      (0,400) (200,400) (400,400)
```

So, there is no gap in between these `UIImageViews`. But in reality there is 1px gap between these views. Strange thing is these gaps occur between different `UIImageView`s for different device configurations:

- I need to scale to 100% for iPhone 4s simulator to see the gap.
- I need to scale to 50% for iPhone 5s simulator to see the gap.
- I need to scale to 75% for iPhone 6 simulator to see the gap.
- I need to scale to 75% for iPhone 6 plus simulator to see the gap.

For iPhone 4s:
[image]

For iPhone 5s:

[image]

For iPhone 6:

[image]

For iPhone 6 plus:

[image]

All the tiles are imageviews  which shows the images . At the end All these tiles together form a single image!!! This is what I am trying to achieve!!!! But I really dont like the gap between these elements!!!!!

Here is my storyboard screenshot:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349072/why-does-ios-auto-layout-lead-to-apparent-rounding-errors-on-pre-retina-displays ?

Comment: do you suggest to chnage the each tile frame to 200,200 or whatever the size divide by 3 during the layout happens?